# Git different user per remote

Tags: git

Is it possible to define a user in `./git/config` per remote like this?

I have mutliple remote with commits that shoud be tagged by the user linked to the remote.

Didn't find any answer on SO for this.

Found the tip with `includeIf` but that's not what I'm seeking.

```
[ remote "toto"]
    url = ssh://127.1.2.3:22/totoremote
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/toto/*
[ user "toto" ]
    name = theUserForToto
    email = theuserfortoto@tata.com
```

Comment: `user.name` and `user.email` config values are used when a commit is created. At that time, there is no remote that plays any part in the process, so it is not possible to do what you are asking.

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but contains the answer to how to set up per-remote authentication.

Comment: Yes it is more about setting username and email for commit depending on remote.